# Convert Java Timestamp to MySQL timestamp vice versa

Tags: java, date, time, timestamp

How can I Convert Java Timestamp (Timestamp data type) to MySQL timestamp vice versa?

Comment: It's not complicated to do in Java. Which framework are you using to access your database?

Comment: I don't use any framework for now

Comment: Please show us the code that is giving you problems, and tell us what the problem is.  As the answers say, no conversion *should be* required.  `java.sql.TimeStamp` should map directly to the MySQL `TIMESTAMP` type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the JDBC API to access the database, and you're using a `PreparedStatement` to for example execute an SQL INSERT statement, then you just set the timestamp as a parameter to the `PreparedStatement`:

```
Timestamp ts = ...; // wherever you get this from

PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ts) VALUES (?)");
ps.setTimestamp(1, ts);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Likewise, when you're doing a query that returns a timestamp, get it from the `ResultSet` by calling `getTimestamp` on it. Example:

```
Timestamp result = null;

Statement st = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT ts FROM MYTABLE WHERE ...");
if (rs.next()) {
    result = rs.getTimestamp(1);
}
```

See the [JDBC Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html).

Comment: Thank you, What I want to do is that when I load data from MySQL, I want to set it as an object that has ctime (TIMESTAMP) in mysql and ctime (Timestamp) in java

Comment: @bn, if you are pulling data out using JDBC ResultSet, you will want to use the getTimestamp() method on it.

Answer (score 3):

Without more specifics on the trouble you are having, this will be a hard question to answer.  However, Java makes this relatively straightforward if you are using prepared statements.  Your code would look something like this:

```
Connection conn = getConnection();
PreparedStatement pStmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE my_table SET my_column = ? WHERE id = ?");
pStmt.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
pStmt.setInt(2, 42);
pStmt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see from MySQL docs, [java.sql.Timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) should just work if you [read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp%28int%29) it from or [write](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp%28int,%20java.sql.Timestamp%29) it to a [TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html) field in the database. So you should not need to do any conversion.